# Debug Steps in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, debugging, class-diagram

Dear All,

I have 3 jsp pages. Lets call it Page A(General Main Page),B(Logic process),C(Displayed on web). 
Page A will redirect to Page B, then Page B redirect to Page C.
I want to print a sql query from Page B. But it will not be displayed on the webpage, because its a redirect page.
So, I comment out the redirect and the add 'input' tag and pass the sql string to the 'input', and now I can view the sql string at the network response tab.

Some of debug methods i known are:
a)System.out.println to tomcat cli
b)out print to page, windows alert, console log
c)preserve log in chrome to have overview of an action flow
d)watch variable in chrome/ide

My question is, are there better ways to debug?
Eg: A plugin or tool in IDE that can instantly displayed diagram overview of  project files. (Like umlet can display relationship diagram if you import a project that only has java files-one type of files)
Is there a plugin that does similar thing in eclipse for web project that has many different types of files like jsp, java, js,html and css.

Comment: Why not just debug the JSPs? A Dynamic Web Project helps you set up the necessary dependencies to have Servlets and JSPs, which you can then launch as a web application so you can debug both kinds of files.

Comment: Step 1: Move Java code out of the JSP. Step 2: Debug the Java code.

Comment: A correctly figured IDE can debug JSP classes too.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen can you give an example?

Comment: @Andreas So means if there are 20 jsp files, I need to take out all java code, and set up a new project in my eclipse IDE and create an object and hardcode the object values, which can be like having 50 fields value to be pass to the java code?

Comment: @Telerik Why would you need to set up a new project? Isn't your project already a Java project? --- Why would you *hardcode* object values?